# I want to put table in asp.net grid view

Tags: asp.net

this is my grid view code given below>

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvReport" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" GridLines="None"
     ShowHeader="true" HorizontalAlign="Left" OnRowCommand="gvReport_RowCommand">
           <Columns>
               <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="User" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left">
                 <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Image id="img" text=<%#Eval("Coupon_Image")%>/>
                 </ItemTemplate>
                 <HeaderStyle Font-Bold="false" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
               </asp:TemplateField>
               <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="">
                 <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Button ID="getCoupon" runat="server" CssClass="btn" Width="145" Height="34"
                            CommandName="getCoupon" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("Coupon_Id")%>' />
                 </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
           </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

In this it showing like this

```
 Image 1    Button
 Image 2    Button
```

actually i want like this type in grid view

```
  Image1            Image2      Image3
  Button            Button      Button
```

Please help me ....
advance thanks

Comment: I assume that you use the standard `GridView` from ASP.NET and not the ASPxGridView provided by DevExpress. If that is true remove the tag.

Comment: There is possible to put table inside the grid view ...

Comment: Why three images and buttons and not 4? What is the datasource?

Comment: Use  a [`DataList`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12424309/in-asp-net-i-grid-view-want-to-put-table#comment16702034_12424309) with [RepeatDirection.Horizontal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeatdirection.aspx).

Comment: Yeah you are right we can use Data List ..In data list i done the process, by using repeat column=3 in data list..But i want in Grid view.

Answer (score 0):

A gridview won't work for this.  Use the Table control for that, and programmably build the rows and columns.  The challenge is the gridview isn't meant to render horizontally.  You may be able to make it work with a repeater or ListView too, as you can have the ListView or repeater render the columns, and the layout template be the table and header row.